# UIScrollView stopping my UIGesture from doing view transition

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

So I am working on this project [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53813770/SMPrototypeB.zip), to test some things that I am interested about, such as view transitions using UIGestures.

I am currently testing how view transitions behave when they have things like UIWebViews and UIScrollViews in them. What I have found out currently is that if you have a UIScrollView bigger than the view frame then the transition (using gestures) is blocked if you are using a UIGesture to change the view. (Such as swipe left or right)

I was wondering if there is a way around this or a solution that I don't know about..

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`

return no for it and see if that works.